# Need help creating a query based on ui filter values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, webshop

It has been a few months now since the launch of our webshop and we are still creating new bling to make it easier for visitors to browse the catalog.

At the moment we are trying to add a filter that filters by product specifications.

Let's say the next options are available

### MEMORY

1. 8 GB
2. 12 GB

### PROCESSOR

1. INTEL
2. AMD A
3. AMD E

The SQL to get all relevant product ID's looks like this at the moment:

```
SELECT `lu_specifications` . * , `app_products`.`id` AS product_id
FROM (
    `lu_specifications` 
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `link_products_specifications` link_products_specifications ON `lu_specifications`.`id` = `link_products_specifications`.`specification_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `app_products` app_products ON `app_products`.`id` = `link_products_specifications`.`product_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `link_categories_products` product_link_categories_products ON `app_products`.`id` = `product_link_categories_products`.`product_id` 
WHERE `product_link_categories_products`.`category_id` =160

AND (
    `lu_specifications`.`id` = '60'
    AND `link_products_specifications`.`pres_value` = '8 GB'
)
AND (
    (
        `lu_specifications`.`id` = '54'
        AND `link_products_specifications`.`pres_value` = 'AMD A'
    )
    OR (
        `lu_specifications`.`id` = '54'
        AND `link_products_specifications`.`pres_value` = 'AMD E'
    )
)
```

In this example SQL the visitor would have selected filter options '8GB', 'AMD A' and 'AMD E'.
So he would like to get a product which is/has (8 GB) AND ( (AMD A) OR (AMD E) ).
Is this method correct? Because we are sure it should return like 17 products, but the SQL returns none, and it does not generate any error.

Could someone point us in the right direction please? :)

Comment: Is the Filter option '8GB' and the comparison '8 GB' just a typo or has one a space, and the other not?

Comment: Ah, that's just a typo :). I'll correct it. In the script it is with space at all times since they are loaded in by filter_option_id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above query will for sure give no results. Because  `lu_specifications`.`id` = '60' at one place and `lu_specifications`.`id` = '54' enclosed in AND condition.
Its a column value, which can contain one value at a time, so both statements can not be TRUE together, which results in FALSE.

May be you want to use OR in following place.
AND (
    `lu_specifications`.`id` = '60'
    AND `link_products_specifications`.`pres_value` = '8 GB'
)
**OR** (
    (
        `lu_specifications`.`id` = '54'
        AND `link_products_specifications`.`pres_value` = 'AMD A'
    )
    OR (
        `lu_specifications`.`id` = '54'
        AND `link_products_specifications`.`pres_value` = 'AMD E'
    )
)

Comment: You nailed it. This is a rewrite of what we had before. The filter combined the result of each selected option (one array with product ID's). However we don't need everything combined in the new version. It should only return ID's from products which have 8 GB and contain a AMD A or AMD E processor. (not everything which has 8 GB or contains an AMD A or AMD E processor).  Hope you get what I try to say here :p

Comment: Would it help to drop the `lu_specifications.id` from all and just query the `link_products_specifications.pres_value` fields??

Comment: Did u check ur underlying table have data for `product_link_categories_products`.`category_id` =160. Also, I guess bracket placing is not correct. Put like below:

Comment: Also, Can you please check below logic once: 
product_link_categories_products`.`category_id` =160
AND ((COndition1) OR (Condition2) OR (Condition3))

Condition is   `lu_specifications`.`id` = something
    AND `link_products_specifications`.`pres_value` = something

Comment: The category_id = 160 are all Laptops, this works since the shop is online.
I did try with all OR's and that resulted in correct values as if we needed it to return products which have '8 GB or contain a AMD A or AMD E processor'. We need products which have '8 GB and contain a AMD A or AMD E'.

Comment: hey Brainfeeder, I just created new profile. if this get ur question resolved can u please give some points :P

Comment: We didn't solve it yet :p opened a new question related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408847/merge-arrays-so-they-contain-only-recurring-values
We do have the product ID's in array's, but now those should be merged somehow....