# Merge arrays so they contain only recurring values

Tags: php, arrays, webshop

We are upgrading a webshop so the filtering is a little bit different. Now we simply get all product ID's which are related to one or more selected filter values.

```
//Filter value '8 GB'
$result[] = array(1,6,5,8,9);

//Filter value 'AMD E' (and)OR 'INTEL'
$result[] = array(1,5,8,9,10,500,502,503,600,607,608,...);
```

The 'AMD E' and 'INTEL' values are from the same filter 'Processor' so we would like these combined as the visitor would like to have all products with an AMD E OR an INTEL processor.

Now we would like to select only the ID's which occur in both array's. We've tried a bunch of methods by now it just doesn't return what we expect in any atempt.

The problem is that the number of key => array pairs in `$result` is dynamic just like the number of ID's returned by SQL. when the first array in `$result` is a short list of ID's, `array_intersect()` will not return all expected results when there are multiple array's in `$result`.

`merge_array()` would just combine everything. So the visitor will see ALL products which have 8 GB memory or which contain a AMD E or INTEL processor.

We are looking for a ('8 GB') AND ('ADM E' OR 'INTEL') solution.

Things get complicated when more filters are activated:
('8 GB' OR '12 GB') AND ('ADM E' OR 'INTEL') AND ('HP' OR 'Apple' OR 'Sony')

(Hope I didn't loose you trying to explain the situation and what we are trying to do by now :s)

We've also tried getting stuff done through SQL. As you can read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403164/need-help-creating-a-query-based-on-ui-filter-values/) without any luck.

Anyone tackled something like this before?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want an intersection of all sub-arrays stored in $results array? If so, please see my answer. If not please elaborate

Comment: Well yes, we would love that, but somehow, if the first sub-array only contains 4 ID's and the later arrays contain more, it will only check the later for the occurance of the 4 ID's in the first sub-array.. Am I right?

Comment: And what if one of the sub-arrays is empty since there are no products for that filter value... The whole function would return no results.

Comment: You're right, but isn't it what you want? If user selects 8GB Ram and AMD E processor and you do not have producst that match those 2 filters, why would you return any product and tell users that it matches their criteria?

Comment: Ok, yes, but.. -this is hard to explain without examples- We have dynamic filter 'groups' for each product category, each filter 'group' contains filter options/values. A group could be 'Processor' or 'Internal memory'. If a user selects 2 options from 'internal memory' they should be queried with 'OR' since one of both options is enough. One of those options result could be empty. A user can select another option from another group. Those should be combined with te previous results with 'AND'..

Comment: I see, I assumed your comment "Filter value 'AMD E' (and)OR 'INTEL'" means that the array already contains results after the OR search. Let me update the answer in a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want to have a 2-step process:

1. Find all items that match any criteria in given filter group
2. Find items that are returned in all used filter groups

For the first step you'll need to find products that match each of selected option. E.g. if user searches for products that have any of options A, B or C, put the results in an array like:

```
$results = [
 [1,2,3], // products that have option A
 [2,5,7], // products that have option B,
 [2,7,10] // products that have option C
];
```

You can now get the IDs of all products that have any of those options using

```
$ids = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $results);
```

This will give you the sum of arrays.

You have to do that for each filter group that user has selected and you'll get another array of arrays on which now you need to do the intersection operation:

```
$result = [
  $ids1, // array of IDs that match ANY option from filter group 1
  $ids2  // array of IDs that match ANY option from filter group 2
];
```

You can get the intersection by calling:

```
$ids = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $results);
```

This will give you IDs of products that match ANY filter option in ALL selected filter groups.

The last thing you'll need is to check if user has selected any filters. If not, do not apply above logic but return all products.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: For the record, I tried it this way, and it seems to work if I `array_multisort(array_map('count', $result), SORT_DESC, $result);` everything before doing the intersect function.

Comment: Damn, I was cheering to early. If i select no filters, the result is completly empty now...

Comment: I like this because we are thinking in the same direction - which means I wasn't going crazy on this - .. In our situation step 1 is handled with a database query. So we allready have the 'merged arrays' ready for step 2.
I'll check if I didn't make any mistake.. But last time I tested this method  was not returning the expected results. At least not in all cases.

Comment: We ended up doing this ($result being the array in your second step)
`array_multisort(array_map('count', $result), SORT_DESC, $result);`
`$filtered = (count($result) == 1)?$result[0]:call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $result);`
 $filtered is the $ids array in your answer.